# Magento warning caused by Varien_Object $this->_data being an object but not an array

Tags: php, magento

I got Magento 1.7 and I got this error `Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given  in ~/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 117`. It's on a plugin that I installed, but I don't know how I can fix it.

The line is

```
$existedShortKeys = array_intersect($this->_syncFieldsMap, array_keys($this->_data));
```

but `$this->_data` is an object... So is it the plugin error or Magento's error ?
The plugin is Affiliate+ http://www.magestore.com/affiliateplus

===== FIX ====
So I managed to fix it, it's just a warning so we see this problem only in developer mode.
On the page `app/code/local/Magestore/Affiliateplus/Block/Adminhtml/Banner/Edit/Tab/Form.phtml` line 7

```
$data = array();
if(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getBannerData()){
    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getBannerData();
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBannerData(null);
} elseif ( Mage::registry('banner_data')) {
    //$data =  Mage::registry('banner_data'); This line must be disabled
}
$obj = new Varien_Object($data);
```

That's it.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the original code - from what I'm seeing in your patch, the protected Varien_Object::_data property couldn't be set to object from this scope anyway?

Comment: Which part of the code do you want ? Because it's a quite big extension... I can copy the code of that method if you want. When there is data in the session it works.

Comment: Whatever code you directly patched would be interesting to see. As long as it works though...

Comment: I only patched the line that I commented, putting more code would be useless for the understanding. But it works like this so it's good :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that it is the plugins error. Normally `$this->_data` is not an object but an arry.

To get more details info you should post the name of the plugin, a link to the code and the backtrace of the error. Or contact the plugin's manufacturer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried to contact them but they are not online yet. It's a payed plugin so I can't give the link to the code. Here is the plugin http://www.magestore.com/affiliateplus/

Comment: Ok found the problem... Now I need to see how to fix it. Thank you for your help

Comment: If it is a payed plugin, there definitely should be support available. Just contact them.

Comment: I contacted them but they are not here... And I need to go further so I can't wait for a reply. I fixed the bug I edit my message so if someone got the same problem one day.